# Inner join does not output id column

Tags: sql, join

I have a query with joins of different tables

```
SELECT 
    cust_name, order_no, order_status, pay_method, pro_name, cust_city 
FROM 
    customers
INNER JOIN 
    orders ON customers.cust_id = orders.cust_id
INNER JOIN 
    pro_orders ON pro_orders.order_id = orders.order_id
INNER JOIN 
    products ON products.pro_id = pro_orders.pro_id 
ORDER BY 
    customers.cust_name ASC
```

I am trying to output `order_id` from orders table & `customer_id` from customer table any id column which is related to other table as relation does not output

Comment: You are printing `cust_name,order_no,order_status,pay_method,pro_name,cust_city`. If you want more columns, add them to the list.

Comment: I understand what you mean but trust me I did that already but still not printing

Comment: If you have the columns in the select statement, they should be in the output. Please modify your question with the query that you say has the columns you want but for some reason isn't printing them.

Comment: If i put this query in phpMyAdmin Sql it gives this error: 1052 column id in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Right, so the problem is *not* that the column does not print, it's that you have a different query to the one you posted, and it gives you an error. Why not post that information to start with?

Comment: Anyway, to fix the error, prefix the column name with the table name and `.`. Eg. `customers.customer_id`.

Comment: oh ya that works with customers.customer_id but why is that only for id column i have to do this?

Comment: any column you want to output **must have** a unique name - you **cannot** have two columns called `id` in your output. And if you have a column in more than one table (like the `customer_id`, you must define from **which table** that column should be taken. And **no**, this is not just for `id` columns - you couldn't have two columns `name` either....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like below

```
    SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name,order_no,order_status,pay_method,pro_name,cust_city 
    FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN orders o ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
    INNER JOIN pro_orders po ON po.order_id = o.order_id
    INNER JOIN products pr ON po.pro_id = pr.pro_id 
    ORDER BY c.cust_name ASC
```

It is because the cust_id column is in both customers and order table. So SQL doesn't know from which table's cust_id should be printed.

Also it is one of the best practices to create aliases and use those aliases in the query. It makes query more readable and less prone to errors like above.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias to avoid the ambiguous

```
SELECT 
    c.*, o.*, po.*, p.*
FROM 
    customers c
INNER JOIN 
    orders  o ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
INNER JOIN 
    pro_orders po ON po.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN 
    products p ON p.pro_id = po.pro_id 
ORDER BY 
    c.cust_name ASC
```